# ACF Select field value in Product Variation with WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am having some issues with getting the value of a select-field to show on product variation. I can get the value of a normal text field without any issue with the code below, but when trying to pull out the chosen select field it shows nothing. Any clue what is causing the issue?

Functions.php:

```
function acf_variation_picker ( $variations ) {

    $variations['select_test'] = get_field('select_test', $variations[ 'variation_id' ]);
    
    return $variations;
}
```

Variation.php:

```
<p><strong>Test 2:</strong> {{{ data.variation.select_test }}} </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the field exists and has a value.
If it does, get the value.
If it doesn't, return null or a default value.

Here is your revised function

```
function acf_variation_picker ( $variations ) {
    $select_test_value = get_field('select_test', $variations[ 'variation_id' ]);

    if($select_test_value) {
        $variations['select_test'] = $select_test_value;
    } else {
        $variations['select_test'] = null; // or a default value
    }

    return $variations;
}
```